# Making Screenshot Script TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'cloneNode')

Tags: javascript, html

Whenever I press Download ScreenShot Button I get this error Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'cloneNode')
at d (dom-to-image.min.js:2:1519)
How do I fix this -
HTML Code for understanding my problem - https://jsfiddle.net/m5gneoL7/

```html
 <button id="dload_img">Download</button>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dom-to-image/2.6.0/dom-to-image.min.js" integrity="sha512-01CJ9/g7e8cUmY0DFTMcUw/ikS799FHiOA0eyHsUWfOetgbx/t6oV4otQ5zXKQyIrQGTHSmRVPIgrgLcZi/WMA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/filesaver.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#dload_img").click(function() {
        domtoimage.toBlob(document.getElementById('whole_page','')).then(function(blob){
          window.saveAs(blob, "output.png");
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, change:

```
<div class="whole_page">
```

to:

```
<div id="whole_page">
```

Because you are using `document.getElementById` to find `whole_page`, it needs to be the `id` of the `div`. If you really wanted to find the div by a `class`, then change the javascript to:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('whole_page')[0]
```

([0] because it returns an array)

I tried your fiddle and that does solve the immediate problem, but that just uncovers other breakage.